# How to write data from text file to excel file row wise using awk?

Tags: excel, bash, awk

I have data in my text file and i want to write those data into excel row wise.

Input file:

```
12784
657
38%
5.5
237
.
.
```

(Excel)Output file:

```
Column_3  Column_4 Column_5 Column_6 Column_7 ...
12784      657      38%      5.5      237
```

as first two rows contains some other data.

i tried:

```
awk '{print $1}' OFS="|" input.txt > OutputObatained.xls
```

but the data got written in only 1st column(Column 1).
Also i want my data from the 3rd column.
And I am writing a script so these data will b added frequently and i have to append every time in new row.
example :
1st output
(Excel)Output file:

```
Column_3  Column_4 Column_5 Column_6 Column_7 ...
12784      657      38%      5.5      237
```

2nd output:

(Excel)Output file:

```
Column_3  Column_4 Column_5 Column_6 Column_7 ...
12784      657      38%      5.5      237
13455      689      40%      6.1      240
```

Like this, I don't want to loose previous data and each time the data should go in new row.

Until now I am able to get data like
(Excel)Output file:

```
Column_1  Column_2 Column_3 Column_4 Column_5 ...
12784      657      38%      5.5      237
```

but i need to have data from 3rd column.and for next every time the data must come in new row.

Comment: Do you want to get an XLS file, or something simpler, like a CSV?

Comment: Think you meant to use `ORS`

Comment: Will your next comment be "oh, but I need more than one row of output"? if so edit your question to clarify. And get rid of all those useless `...`s from your example.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data you show

```
paste - - - - - < input.txt > output.csv
```

The output file will have tab-separated data.

Depending on how many columns you actually have, the series of hyphens can be dynamically generated. Or, use awk:

```
awk -v cols=5 '{printf "%s%s", $1, (NR % cols == 0 ? "\n" : "\t")}' input > output
```

Comment: thanx @glenn jackman i tried this and the data is coming in single row what i wanted. but i wanted the data to be written from 3rd column so is there any way or you would like to share any documents for help. Thanks